# Generic method in java - can not resolve method 'someMethod' in T

Tags: java, generics

I am new to the concept of generics in Java. I have a generic method whose return type is also a generic.

I am getting this error, `can not resolve method 'getAa' in T`. Both classes do have this member variable but java does not understand this as the sub method returns a generic list of that object. Is there a way to get rid of this error?

Below is my code,

```
class A {
    int aa;
    int bb;

    int getAa() {
        return 1;
    }

}

class B {
    int aa;
    int cc;

    int getAa() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

```
class C {
    private <T> T genericMethodName(String s, Class<T> objectType) {
        List<T> AlistOrBlist = method which returns a list of objects of A or B
        AlistOrBlist = AlistOrBlist.stream()
                                    .filter(record -> record.getAa().equals(""))
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        return AlistOrBlist.get(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Declaring a field `aa` does not automatically create a method `getAa`.

Comment: Yeah, I have used the annotation in my actual code, forgot to paste it here. But I do have the method getAa() in both classes.

Comment: But aside from that, `<T>` has no bounds, so `genericMethodName` can only assume that items in the list are `Object`. You need to have A and B implement a common interface which has the `getAa()` method on it. Then you can make the type variable be `<T extends HasAa>`.

Answer (score 0):

An easy approach here is to make `A` and `B` inherit from a common parent that declares a `getAa()` method. This could be a simple interface.

If, however, `A` and `B` **must** remain unrelated, you can make the caller send the "getter" function that's applicable to the concrete type for `T`.

```
private <T> T genericMethodName(String s, ToIntFunction<T> mapper) {
    List<T> AlistOrBlist = method which returns a list of objects of A or B
    AlistOrBlist = AlistOrBlist.stream()
            .filter(record -> mapper.applyAsInt(record) == 0)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return AlistOrBlist.get(0);
}
```

If you're using `objectType` in the call to resolve `AlistOrBlist`, you can still take it in as well. And if `getAa()` returns a different type than `int`, you can type `mapper` as `Function<T, ReturnTypeOfGetAa>`.

You call that in this way:

```
A result = c.genericMethodName("param", A::getAa);
B result = c.genericMethodName("param", B::getAa);
```